# How should multiple Spring applications (OpenJPA, Tomcat) use a single object store?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, openjpa

What are some techniques for allowing multiple Spring applications to share a single set of persistent domain objects?

This is Spring 3.0, using OpenJPA [and a Postgres database but that shouldn't matter], all running in a Tomcat 7 server. I have two applications (one providing a fairly typical Web MVC interface and one providing SOAP web services) that each access the same underlying entities.

If I deploy the three modules (entities, MVC, and webservices) separately, and if entities is the only one with a persistence context, entity manager, etc., how is it that the other modules can get hold of the entity manager, retrieve and update objects, etc.?

Is there any option beside incorporating them in a single EAR and deploying that?

Comment: L2 cache, exactly, but what are some generally accepted ways of accessing it cross-module?